# javascript inheritance similar to Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been looking into backbone.js and the inheritance used in backbone looks good. Further research landed me with this link http://blog.usefunnel.com/2011/03/js-inheritance-with-backbone/

Any suggestions regarding a better way/ other options for inheritance in javascript?

Comment: Did  you look at coffeescript? It'll make your life quite simple for such things. It automatically sets up the correct inheritance (i.e., setting the appropriate prototype(s)) and the syntax is highly OO :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this approach: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Answer (score 1):

An option to inheritance are Traits which are similar to mixins in Ruby. Check out [traits.js](http://traitsjs.org/).